Question about Bohr/Einstein recoiling slits experiment
I have a burning question about the Einstein/Bohr recoiling slits experiment I've found explained by Feynman towards the bottom of this page: https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_01.html
Being a computer scientist and not a physicist, I've found it impossible to follow how Feynman arrives at the conclusion that the interference pattern must get washed out as a result of the uncertainty in the position of the plate containing the double slits.
The part I do understand
Precise position information can be obtained by observing the plate. If the plate moves up, it means the particle's going through hole 1. If the plate moves down, it means the particle's going through hole 2.
Precise simultaneous momentum information at hole 1 or 2 would have been possible if we could know the plate's initial momentum precisely (can't assume it's precisely zero like Einstein assumed).
Measuring the plate's initial momentum makes one lose knowledge of where hole 1 and hole 2 are (more position uncertainty).
Precise position information can be obtained by observing the plate. If the plate moves up, it means the particle's going through hole 1. If the plate moves down, it means the particle's going through hole 2.
Precise simultaneous momentum information at hole 1 or 2 would have been possible if we could know the plate's initial momentum precisely (can't assume it's precisely zero like Einstein assumed).
Measuring the plate's initial momentum makes one lose knowledge of where hole 1 and hole 2 are (more position uncertainty).
The part I don't understand
Measuring the plate's initial momentum makes one lose knowledge of where hole 1 and hole 2 are. But then what happens? Losing the position of the holes somehow washes out the interference pattern, Feynman describes, which I'm unable to follow. Shouldn't the position uncertainty let the interference pattern remain intact instead of destroying it? What am I missing here? Feynman seems to describe the superposition of different paths caused by the position uncertainty, I do know what the superposition principle is and how it works but I'm still not following what Feynman describes.
Thank you so much for clarifying without using mathematics, much appreciated.

Putting text in all caps is very likely to get your question not taken seriously and possibly even closed.

The OP has an earlier attempt at this question: Trying to understand Einstein/Bohr recoiling slits thought experiment, please help.

When asking two closely related questions, it is best to refer to the earlier question and to be clear how the new question differs from the earlier question. If the questions are essentially the same, however, instead of asking the second question, it is best to edit and improve the earlier question.

Feynman is giving you an awful piece of misinformation here that serves very little educational purpose. First things first: There are no particles in quantum mechanics. What we are measuring are quanta of energy, momentum, angular momentum and charge. If we introduce a mechanism in the scattering process (on the double slit) in which the quantum from the light source (or electron gun) moves a classical piece of matter, then it necessarily either loses or gains energy (Doppler effect on a moving mirror) and it changes its momentum vector. It ceases to be the same quantum. Since the energy/momentum transfer between the electromagnetic/electron field is not deterministic, the outgoing wave after the double slit does not have the same coherence that the incoming wave from the source had. In case of a "hard" quantum measurement there is no more outgoing wave because the quantum's energy will be fully absorbed by the measurement system at the slit. So what really happens to the "path measured double slit" is that it becomes two independent single slits (or, if we cover up one slit with a hard detector permanently, then we get a single slit diffraction pattern). If we perform weak measurements (which are NOT covered by the simple Schroedinger equation/Born rule formalism!), then we are gradually degrading the coherence of the outgoing wave fronts and the resulting patterns will be somewhere between two single slits and the double slit pattern.
This has nothing to do with the uncertainty relation, either, because we are not actually restricting the extent of the wave function with a double slit. It still fills almost all of the spatial volume (with the exception of the null-volume of the slit). Textbooks which are handwaving with Heisenberg to "solve" physical problems do, in my honest opinion, tell us more about the limited interest of their authors to actually engage with the theory at more than a paper thin level than they tell us about the theory itself. There is, unfortunately, a lot of that out there in the undergrad textbook space. End rant.

This unfortunately does not the answer to my question.

@AsliTheobald It tells you that the mental model of particles is wrong and that you will never be able to develop a self-consistent intuitive understanding of what is actually going on in quantum mechanics with this level of understanding. I can't answer your question in the false framework in which it is posed. Quantum mechanics simply does not work this way. You have to learn to think in terms of quanta, i.e. small amounts of energy, momentum., angular momentum and charge that are being exchanged between systems. Feynman does not even attempt to teach you that.

This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - From Review

@MichaelSeifert One can not give a physically correct answer to the question. It is formulated in a framework that does not exist in proper quantum mechanics. I know that this is an unpopular answer, but it is an answer. There is no such thing as "which way" in quantum mechanics.
